# Nativescript can't get slide event

Tags: slider, slide, nativescript

how can I get the slide event for slider ? I tried

```
slider.on('slide', function(){
  console.log('slide!');
});
```

and

```
slider.on('change', function(){
  console.log('slide!');
});
```

but it doesnt work :(( Thanks in advance.﻿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bind](https://docs.nativescript.org/bindings.html) the slide value to an [observable object](https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/data/observable/HOW-TO.html) and then listen to the `propertyChangeEvent` of that object.

**Example**

Given you have an XML looking like this:

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded">
    <StackLayout>
        <Slider value="{{ sliderValue }}" />
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Then you can write your binding and event like this:

```
var observable = require("data/observable");

function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var viewModel = new observable.Observable();
    viewModel.set('sliderValue', 42);
    page.bindingContext = viewModel;

    viewModel.on(observable.Observable.propertyChangeEvent, function(propertyChangeData){
        //Do your magic here
    });

}
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

Data bindings and Observable Objects are *key parts* of NativeScript. I highly recommend reading the documentation and get yourself familiar with them:

- https://docs.nativescript.org/bindings.html
- https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/data/observable/HOW-TO.html

Comment: Yey!! It works like a charm :) Thank you very much :)